# fiji macro how to use given luts and plugin

Tags: macros, imagej

I need to write a macro in Fiji.
First I record a macro to do what I wanted. The result was the following:

```
run("Size...", "width=512 height=512 depth=497 average interpolation=None");
run("Rotate 90 Degrees Right");
run("Flip Horizontally", "stack");
run("Make Substack...", "  slices=5-300");
run("isolum_cbs_strict");
run("Z Code Stack", "depth=Current");
run("Z Project...", "start=1 stop=296 projection=[Standard Deviation]");
```

I would like to do it in a batch mode. So I write a macro myself:

```
file = getArgument;
if (file=="") exit ("No argument!");
setBatchMode(true);
file_vasc = file;
open(file_vasc);
run("Size...", "width=512 height=512 depth=497 average interpolation=None");
run("Rotate 90 Degrees Right");
run("Flip Horizontally", "stack");
run("Make Substack...", "  slices=5-200");
run("isolum_cbs_strict"); 
run("Z Code Stack", "depth=Current");
run("Z Project...", "start=1 stop=196 projection=[Max Intensity]");
file_vasc_out = replace(file, "\\_pvar-8bit_combined.tif", "_maxZprojection.tif");
saveAs("Tiff", file_vasc);
```

However I got macro errors as undefined variable for `run("isolum_cbs_strict")` and a unrecognized command for `run("Z Code Stack", "depth=Current")`.
How can I access to this lut which is in:

```
C:\Program Files\Fiji.app\luts\isolum_cbs.lut
```

and to the plugin which is in:

```
C:\Program Files\Fiji.app\plugins\Stacks - Z-functions
```

Thanks for your help,

Corinne

Comment: How are you running your macro? From the command line? The command `run("isolum_cbs")` works as expected when I put an `isolum_cbs.lut` in Fiji's `luts` folder. Are you sure all names are correct?

Comment: I am using the following command line to run my macro:
"C:\Program Files\Fiji.app\java\win64\jdk1.6.0_24\jre\bin\java.exe" -Dplugins.dir=Fiji.app\ -jar "C:\Program Files\Fiji.app\jars\ij.jar" -batch D:\function D:\img1.tif 

what I do not understand is that if I execute the command run(""isolum_cbs_strict) in Fiji by doing Plugin>Macros>Run it is working... 
I imagine I have to define where to find the luts folder but I did not find the way of doing it in the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to provide `-ijpathpath` as argument to Fiji. Then, luts, plugins, etc. are all derived relatively to this path. In other words, pass the following argument:

> -ijpathpath "C:\Program Files\Fiji.app"

Note that, importantly, you must not have a backslash at the end of the path.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the java runtime to start Fiji/ImageJ, use the provided launcher execuable to run your macro:

```
fiji-win64.exe D:\your_macro.ijm D:\your_image.tif
```

or (which is essentially the same):

```
ImageJ-win64.exe D:\your_macro.ijm D:\your_image.tif
```

The ImageJ launcher takes care to provide all the necessary environment to run macros and scripts from the command line. It even provides a `--headless` option to run your script without even showing the user interface. See Fiji's [Headless documentation](http://fiji.sc/Headless).